# SVG element bounding box covering elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm running into the issue of the transparent portions of the SVG still covering mouse events of objects below it. A [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bseverson/pqf8014n/) that shows a very simplified example. I at first thought this was an issue of all items being seperate SVG elements that are embeded with the `object` tag, but this issue seems to pop up even with inline elements, such as the example in the page.

If you mouse over either circle the pointer changes as desired, but if you hover over the blue circle where the bounding box of the red circle overlaps you lose the pointer interaction.

I'm trying to find an easy way to allow these to pass-through. I had heard using the css `pointer-events` property would fix this issue, but if I put it on any higher element as `'none'` it will take all child events out too it seems.

Here is the code snippet in case you didn't want to check over on jsFiddle.

```js
// Get all svgs
var svgElems = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");

// loop the list
for (let svgElem of svgElems) {
  // grab the first group element inside
  var gElem = svgElem.getElementsByTagName("g")[0];

  // set the style for the cursor to a pointer
  gElem.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}
```

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="interaction-spot" style="position: absolute; width: 50%; top: 5%; left:10%; z-index:5">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164 164">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:#030093;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>blue</title>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
      <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
        <circle class="cls-1" cx="82" cy="82" r="82"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="interaction-spot" style="position: absolute; width: 50%; top: 5%; left:25%; z-index:5">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164 164">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-2{fill:#af0000;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>red</title>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
      <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
        <circle class="cls-2" cx="82" cy="82" r="82"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set pointer-events: none on the container, and reset it in the inner element

```js
// Get all svgs
var svgElems = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");

// loop the list
for (let svgElem of svgElems) {
  // grab the first group element inside
  var gElem = svgElem.getElementsByTagName("g")[0];

  // set the style for the cursor to a pointer
  gElem.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}
```

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.interaction-spot {
    pointer-events: none;
}


#Layer_1-2 {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="interaction-spot" style="position: absolute; width: 50%; top: 5%; left:10%; z-index:5">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164 164">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:#030093;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>blue</title>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
      <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
        <circle class="cls-1" cx="82" cy="82" r="82"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div id="red" class="interaction-spot" style="position: absolute; width: 50%; top: 5%; left:25%; z-index:5">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164 164">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-2{fill:#af0000;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>red</title>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
      <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
        <circle class="cls-2" cx="82" cy="82" r="82"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is actually the better option, since I don't have to generate and hold clip-path masks for every object within the final warehouse for the project I need this for. I think I didn't realize you need to reset the interactions below the top.

Comment: @BeauSeverson You are right. I have changed the selectors to classes, now we have the exact behavior wanted. (And a cleaner solution)

Comment: I would just like to add a note here. This functionality doesn't apply if you are using SVGs placed with the `Object` embed method of using SVGs. I can apply the `pointer-events` to any element inside the SVG, but if I remove the events from the object tag, which contains the document and all SVG elements, it won't seem to let any hover events ripple up through it anymore.

Comment: Using Object creates a sort of shadow dom ... You can not reach it with CSS (usually) but you can with inline style. See here https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clip-path`:

```
.interaction-spot {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8be7xy9/)**

Comment: I looked at your jsFiddle and I was surprised that the clip-path circle was about 20px larger than the svg circle. I set the background to black and it made it more obvious. `circle(50%)` matched it a lot better... weird

Comment: @TheCrzyMan I didn't pay much attention on the size, as the svg width and height can be different from the viewBox values. Thanks for pointing that out, now updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually assign an ID to individual elements in your SVG -- just open the SVG in your editor to access the SVGs DOM and add id="someelement" to any elements you want to pass through and then resave the SVG. Then, you can apply pointer-events:none just to the specific elements you want to pass through clicks by simply targeting the ID.

```
svg#someelement, svg#sometherelement, svg#yetanotherelement{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the thing I need to pass through is the bounding box of the SVG element. For some reason even if I only put an event on a particular element inside the SVG, so the pointer only triggers when hovering over that element, the bounding box of the SVG tag itself seems to still cover any HTML elements below it.